# How to sort by Maximum number of rows in SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

**I have this stored procedure and I want to sort by number of total result returns. Means customer with maximum orders must come first and so on 
Following is my stored procedure.**

```
BEGIN
  SELECT    Customer.Customer_Name, Item.Item_Name, 
       Count(Item.Item_Name)  , Customer_Sale.Quantity_Customer,
       Customer_Sale.Sale_Price ,Customer_Sale.Total_Price,  
       Customer_Sale.Date ,Total_Remaining_Previous, Today_Credit, 
       Total_Remaining_Now  , Today_Receiving , Total_Xhot
FROM         Customer  JOIN
                         Customer_Sale ON Customer.Customer_Id = Customer_Sale.Customer_Id INNER JOIN
                         Customer_Account on Customer.Customer_Id=Customer_Account.Customer_Id inner join 
                         Unit ON Customer_Sale.Unit_Id = Unit.Unit_Id INNER JOIN
                         Item ON Customer_Sale.Item_Id = Item.Item_Id 

                         WHERE  Customer_Sale.Date = @date and Customer_Account.Customer_Date=@date 
                          group by Item.Item_Name

END
```

Comment: Which DBMS? Also, likely unpredictable results due to single column aggregation with multiple columns returned. Provide sample data and expected result for best answers.

Comment: Sql server management studio is the DBMS and I have removed Count and group by .

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap your query in parenthesis and do a `SELECT * FROM () ORDER BY ORDER_COLUMN_NAME`?

Comment: Actually I want order by total row count of each customer i tried your way but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I am Assuming that the “Count(Item.Item_Name)” is your attempt at this.
You have to use the Over clause like this:

```
SELECT
Customer.Customer_Name
,Item.Item_Name
,Count(Item.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer.Customer_Name) AS ItemCount
,Customer_Sale.Quantity_Customer
,Customer_Sale.Sale_Price
,Customer_Sale.Total_Price
,Customer_Sale.Date
,Total_Remaining_Previous
,Today_Credit
,Total_Remaining_Now
,Today_Receiving
,Total_Xhot
```

FROM
    Customer
INNER JOIN
    Customer_Sale
    ON
        Customer.Customer_Id = Customer_Sale.Customer_Id
INNER JOIN
    Customer_Account
    ON
        Customer.Customer_Id = Customer_Account.Customer_Id
INNER JOIN
    Unit
    ON
        Customer_Sale.Unit_Id = Unit.Unit_Id
INNER JOIN
    Item
    ON
        Customer_Sale.Item_Id = Item.Item_Id 
WHERE
    Customer_Sale.Date = @date
AND Customer_Account.Customer_Date = @date

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
BEGIN
        SELECT   Customer.Customer_Name ,
                 Item.Item_Name ,
                 COUNT(Item.Item_Name) ,
                 Customer_Sale.Quantity_Customer ,
                 Customer_Sale.Sale_Price ,
                 Customer_Sale.Total_Price ,
                 Customer_Sale.Date ,
                 Total_Remaining_Previous ,
                 Today_Credit ,
                 Total_Remaining_Now ,
                 Today_Receiving ,
                 Total_Xhot
        FROM     Customer
                 JOIN Customer_Sale ON Customer.Customer_Id = Customer_Sale.Customer_Id
                 INNER JOIN Customer_Account ON Customer.Customer_Id = Customer_Account.Customer_Id
                 INNER JOIN Unit ON Customer_Sale.Unit_Id = Unit.Unit_Id
                 INNER JOIN Item ON Customer_Sale.Item_Id = Item.Item_Id
        WHERE    Customer_Sale.Date = @date
                 AND Customer_Account.Customer_Date = @date
        GROUP BY Item.Item_Name;
        ORDER BY COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer.Customer_Name) DESC
    END;
```